# Can volumes-from be disabled for docker.image().inside() in a Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline

The Jenkins docker pipeline provides a very nice docker.image().inside() function. This will result in a docker run command like:

```
docker run -t -d -u 1000:1000 -w /var/jenkins_home/workspace/my-job --volumes-from 30dfde62097dad7873b0c72da82f70252jefewfr72edb412c2e759303d10 -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** my-image:latest cat
```

The `--volumes-from` parameter will provide the container with the same volumes as the main Jenkins container. So it will also expose the entire /var/jenkins_home directory. 
Sometimes I would like to execute commands in a container and only expose the current job workspace.

Is it possible to disable/remove the `--volumes-from` parameter?

I can add an extra `-v ${WORKSPACE}:/workspace` myself as args, but I can't find a way to disable/remove the `--volumes-from` parameter.

**Update**:
I also created a JIRA issue for this https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-57655

Comment: It sounds like what you really want here is a Docker agent, which does conveniently and coincidentally allow argument manipulation.

Comment: if you have the actual custom command that you would like to run on your docker host, why not to run it without the plugin?